# Get EC2 meta-data from 196.254.169.254

Tags: amazon-ec2, metadata

I've instanced a new **ec2** and when I try to call the metadata from **196.254.169.254** i got a timeout.

Can someone explain me why?

P.S. The instance is in the new Region *ue-south-1*

Thanks

Stefano G.

Comment: [Retrieving instance metadata - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)

Answer (score 2):

The ip should be:  169.254.169.254